# Order a list of edges to make the the complexity of searching for an edge O(lg E)

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, binary-search

I was reading [this article](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/graph-representation/a/representing-graphs) on how to represent graphs, and probably the simplest way to think about it is to have a list of edges, with an edget being usually a list of the vertices that are related (connected).

Now, at a certain point, there's a question:

> How can you organize an edge list to make searching for a particular edge take 
>   O(lg E) time?

I was thinking to the trivial solution of sorting, but it is not so easy to sort a list of edges. For example, let the following be our initial list of edges:

```
[[3, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

Now, if we try to sort it by using the first vertex, we obtain:

```
[[1, 3], [1, 2], [3, 2]]
```

I am not visualizing well if this search would be `O(lg E)`, where `E` is the number of edges.

Could you please explain how could we organize the edges in order to have a *edge searching algorithm* with a time complexity of `O(lg E)`? And why it should be `O(lg E)`?

Answer (score 3):

*Any* total order will do; more is not needed for sorting and searching with binary search in a sorted list.

The lexicographic order would be a canonical choice for sorting tuples.

If your elements are (unordered) sets (e.g. edges of undirected graphs) you can sort them before comparing by the order on tuples as well.